# A specific word for "oblivious to love"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a specific word describing obliviousness to love, or romance. This is fairly popular in many shounen manga where the protagonist is often completely oblivious to the advances of many girls who are his friends or part of his harem, etc.

I was wondering if there was an adjective to best describe "oblivious to love"?

Answer (score 2):

[*Clueless*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clueless) is a term clearly broader in use than any romantic situation, but it certainly captures the way I felt when I was that guy.

> completely or hopelessly bewildered, unaware, ignorant, or foolish

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **blind to love**.

Example from the [lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/open-your-eyes-to-love-lyrics-lmnt.html) of "The Lizzie McGuire Movie":

```
You've been searching the world to find true love
Looking in all the wrong places
When all of the time you've been blind to love
As plain as the nose on your faces
```

Comment: I'm torn between saying "+1 for using Lizzie McGuire as a reference" and "-100 for using Lizzie McGuire as a reference" :-)

Comment: @jimm101 - I am deeply ashamed: Disney channel is perhaps not the best choice for a litterary reference :(.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, such people are referred to as ***naive***, or ***unsophisticated***.
Since you are probably looking for a more endearing term, you might consider:

- [***unassuming***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unassuming): not having or showing a desire to be noticed, praised, etc.

If you don't mind using a slangy term:

- [***adorkable***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adorkable): Adorable in a dorky, socially awkward manner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an exact such word, but you might come close with "aloof:"

> [Aloof](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aloof): at a distance, especially in feeling or interest; apart:
>   *They always stood aloof from their classmates.*

Paraphrasing the dictionary's example with your scenario: *The protagonist seems aloof to the many girls...*

Comment: An aloof person is not oblivious to romantic advances; an aloof person rather does not care about romantic advances.